# Return unique record from MSSQL table which date is lesser than or equal the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have EmpDept table which keep the history of employee assignment to different department.

```
RECNO       EMPNO       DEPTNO      EFFECTIVEDATE
2051        J000012     1           2011-09-16
7322        J000012     3           2018-09-07
2055        J000016     1           2013-05-16
7312        J000016     3           2018-07-09
7320        J000016     3           2018-09-07
7313        J000016     1           2018-09-09
7316        J000016     1           2018-09-15
7390        J000040     2           2017-05-10
7391        J000040     1           2018-09-09
7392        J000040     5           2018-09-10
8912        J000039     1           2018-09-11
```

If today's date is '2018-09-12',
Parameter @DeptNo = 1,
Expected Output:

```
RECNO       EMPNO       DEPTNO      EFFECTIVEDATE
8912        J000039     1           2018-09-11
7313        J000016     1           2018-09-09
```

Because only EMPNO = J000039 and J000016  having EFFECTIVE DATE less than or equal to '2018-09-12', other records which date less than or equal to today's date are belong to other DeptNo.

From the given record of the table there are 4 distinct EMPNO having DEPTNO=1 
these are (J000012, J000016, J000039, J000040).
If a query has to be done to display its unique record where EFFECTIVEDATE < = GETDATE()
below are the results:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM EMPDEPT
WHERE EMPNO='J000012' AND
EFFECTIVEDATE <=GETDATE()
ORDER BY EFFECTIVEDATE DESC

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM EMPDEPT
WHERE EMPNO='J000016' AND
EFFECTIVEDATE <=GETDATE()
ORDER BY EFFECTIVEDATE DESC

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM EMPDEPT
WHERE EMPNO='J000039' AND
EFFECTIVEDATE <=GETDATE()
ORDER BY EFFECTIVEDATE DESC

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM EMPDEPT
WHERE EMPNO='J000040' AND
EFFECTIVEDATE <=GETDATE()
ORDER BY EFFECTIVEDATE DESC
```

The output are respectively:

```
RECNO   EMPNO   DEPTNO  EFFECTIVEDATE
7322    J000012 3       2018-09-07

RECNO   EMPNO   DEPTNO  EFFECTIVEDATE
7313    J000016 1       2018-09-09

RECNO   EMPNO   DEPTNO  EFFECTIVEDATE
8912    J000039 1       2018-09-11

RECNO   EMPNO   DEPTNO  EFFECTIVEDATE
7392    J000040 5       2018-09-10
```

Based on that results, going back to the requirements,
Below are the output because these are only records belong to DEPTNO = 1
which EFFECTIVEDATE is < = GETDATE(), other EMPNO the lates DEPTNO is not equal to 1.

```
RECNO   EMPNO   DEPTNO  EFFECTIVEDATE
7313    J000016 1       2018-09-09
8912    J000039 1       2018-09-11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would you `WITH TIES` and a window function to be easy....

```
select top 1 * with ties
from yourTable
where DEPTNO = @DeptNo and EFFECTIVEDATE < getdate()
order by row_number() over (partition by EmpNo order by EFFECTIVEDATE desc)
```

For larger data-sets, then I'd use the same logic in a `CTE`

```
;with cte as (
    select
       *
       ,RN = row_number() over (partition by EmpNo order by EFFECTIVEDATE desc)
    from yourTable
    where EFFECTIVEDATE < getdate())

select * 
from cte
where RN = 1   And DEPTNO = @DeptNo
```

Comment: I made additional clarifications above.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by your last comment. Does this not produce the intended results?

Comment: it must only return 2 records see above

Comment: Your code returns 4 records, it must not return the record of EMPNO= J000012 and J000040 because there latest DEPTNO is not belong to 1 anymore.

Comment: @EliseoJr  run my bottom query and see if that is what you desire.

Comment: Ohhh! Yeah, that is the one that I need. Very precise and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by employee number and department number.  Something like this should do it.

```
declare @DeptNo as INTEGER
declare @Date as DATE

SET @DeptNo = 1
set @Date = '2018-09-12'

SELECT RECNO, EMPNO, DEPTNO, MAX(EFFECTIVEDATE) 
FROM EmpDept
WHERE EFFECTIVEDATE <= @Date
AND DEPTNO = @DeptNo
GROUP BY RECNO, EMPNO, DEPTNO
```

Results:

```
2051    J000012 1   2011-09-16
2055    J000016 1   2013-05-16
7313    J000016 1   2018-09-09
8912    J000039 1   2018-09-11
7391    J000040 1   2018-09-09
```

Comment: That will display multiple record of a single employee, as employee could transfer from one department to another and possibly return to the same department as time pass by. I need to display only 1 record for each employee.

Comment: Updated to reflect your requirements.

Comment: It does not display the expected output. As the concept is to return the record like top 1 of EmpNo where EmpNo = <EmpNoValue> And EffectiveDate <= GetDate() but those EmpNo having DeptNo=1 as parameter. The same output I have shown in my problem.

Comment: I didn't want to do the whole thing.  You could have tried a little bit.  I finally installed SQL Server on my linux computer so I could solve it.  The SQL was correct except the WHERE and the GROUP BY were reversed.  Please help me help you.  Anyways, query works just fine now.

Comment: I think they only want one record for each employee

Comment: I have made additional dissection on above problem. Kindly check.